# Memory Leaks at JSON Parsing ,

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

Im facing memory leaks in many cases when I try to parse JSON. Thought its telling SBJsonParser , I know that wont be a cause.

```
- (id)JSONValue {
    SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
    id repr = [jsonParser objectWithString:self]; // 100.0 % Memory Leak
    if (!repr)
        NSLog(@"-JSONValue failed. Error is: %@", jsonParser.error);
    [jsonParser release];
    return repr;
}
```

and also memory leak happening at

```
"id result=[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"result"]; " 
// 100.0% memory leak
id repr = [jsonParser objectWithString:self]; // 80.0% Memory Leak
```

What I need to do to fix this > :( Thanks.

Comment: is your code under ARC or not?

Comment: Most likely the leak (if there is a leak at all) is due to your not properly releasing either the parser itself or an object that was returned by the parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this instead :

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Comment: This answer is correct. In a project I created for a client the SBJsonParser was the cause of some very strange and hard to track down memory leaks. Using the JSON parsing logic supplied with iOS fixed the leak issue. Use NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: But, still im getting many in :( id repr = [jsonParser objectWithString:self];

Comment: You shouldn't use that anymore , when you receive the data from NSURLConnnection or other method you use ,  you should direclty use that line of code to retrieve the JSON.

Comment: ho! sure , Thank you SorynGod!